# GUI: Why is the modal dialog/window called in such a way "Modal"?

Tags: ui, dialog

I searched the web, but I can only find information that explains what the modal dialog is. I would like to know *why* it's called that. The modality defined in that [way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modality_(natural_language)).

> In linguistics and philosophy, modality is the phenomenon whereby language is used to discuss possible situations. For instance, a modal expression may convey that something is likely, desirable, or permissible. Quintessential modal expressions include modal auxiliaries such as "could", "should", or "must"; modal adverbs such as "possibly" or "necessarily"; and modal adjectives such as "conceivable" or "probable". However, modal components have been identified in the meanings of countless natural language expressions including counterfactuals, propositional attitudes, evidentials, habituals, and generics.

Is its meaning is derived from `must` or similar? Or does it have another origin?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Apple hardware or software as described in the Help Center.

Comment: I missed this out that the site regards to Apple due to site's button has no any hint on this except the Apple `control` button image https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @IconDaemon Note, that your edit changed the meaning of the original question. I was able to find what the modal dialog is, but nothing on why it's called that way...

Comment: I've fixed the intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're starting from the wrong definition of *mode*

Etymologically, from the latin *modus* [as in the commonly-used *modus operandi* - method of operation, or working method.]
<sub>Etymological definition from Oxford Dictionary via Google</sub>

> late Middle English (in the musical and grammatical senses): from Latin modus ‘measure’, from an Indo-European root shared by mete; compare with mood.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mode)

> ### mode (noun) WAY
>
> **a way of operating, living, or behaving:**
>
> - Each department in the company has its own mode of operation.
> - Railways are an important mode of transport for the economy.
> - Switch your phone to silent mode.

From [Wikipedia - Mode (user interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(user_interface))

> In user interface design, a mode is a distinct setting within a computer program or any physical machine interface, in which the same user input will produce perceived results different from those that it would in other settings.

Then from [Wikipedia - Modal Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

> In user interface design for computer applications, a modal window is a graphical control element subordinate to an application's main window.
>
> A modal window creates a mode that disables the main window but keeps it visible, with the modal window as a child window in front of it. Users must interact with the modal window before they can return to the parent application. This avoids interrupting the workflow on the main window. Modal windows are sometimes called heavy windows or modal dialogs because they often display a dialog box.

So, in effect, a modal dialog changes the method/mode of operation/interaction with the application, as it must be completed/dismissed before you can return to the normal mode of operation. You cannot get 'behind' a modal dialog to interact with the application as normal.